# Sort collection efficiently by user-specific field

Tags: mongodb

Imagine an application with an items collection where:

- Users can share/collaborate on the list of items (like a todo app or something)
- Items collection is very long, should be paginated, and sorted by different criterias

Currently it's quite easy to sort by criterias like item creation date, item author name.

But now, each user should be able to set a user-specific priority to each item, and be able to sort that list by priority. An item can have one priority by user , not globally. By default, items with no priority set should appear last

I'd like to know how can I perform pagination/sort efficiently with such a requirement.

If I have N users, it seems not a good idea to have N indexes on the items collection, nor to create dynamically a new index everytime a new user signs up.

Here's a mongoshell script with some fake data and the kind of query I'd like to do

```
db.test.insert({ item: "stample2", "userId1": {priority: 2}});
db.test.insert({ item: "stample0", "userId1": {priority: 0}});
db.test.insert({ item: "stampleUndefined", "userId1": {}});
db.test.insert({ item: "stample3", "userId1": {priority: 3}});
db.test.insert({ item: "stample1", "userId1": {priority: 1}});

db.test.find().sort({ "userId1.priority": -1 }).pretty();
```

Any idea?

Note that it's totally OK to change the modelisation as long as your proposal solves my business requirement to display to the user a paginated list of items sorted by user-specific priority.

---

## I have: a list of items created by different users collaboratively

- Item1
- Item2
- Item3
- Item4
- Item5

Items UI view is paginated and items are ordered by default by creation date descending:

- Item5
- Item4
- Item3
- Item2
- Item1

## New app interaction: users set priorities on items

The priority is not global per item. 2 distinct users can set a different priority for the exact same item.

Let's say User1 set:

- Priority 1 on item3
- Priority 2 on item5
- Other items don't have a priority set for User1

Let's say User2 set:

- Priority 2 on item3
- Priority 3 on item1
- Other items don't have a priority set for User2

## Expected result: UI view should display items (paginated) sorted by priority

More exactly, I want to sort items by priority first (null/undefined user-priority last), then sorted by creation date descending. Each user will get a different order.

User1 should get:

- Item5 (p=2)
- Item3 (p=1)
- Item4 (p=undefined)
- Item2 (p=undefined)
- Item1 (p=undefined)

User2 should get:

- Item1 (p=3)
- Item3 (p=2)
- Item5 (p=undefined)
- Item4 (p=undefined)
- Item2 (p=undefined)

Comment: Kind of broad. Do you think you could narrow down with some specific use cases? is it "really" as case of each user needing to set such on value on each "item"? Or perhaps is it reasonable to save something like a "user preferences" somewhere, which could be applied as a variable? By that I mean something like a list `["t-shirt", "shoes", "handbag"]` that the user "prefers" and then give more "weight" to items with those "attributes" if not filtering out items with those "attributes" all together. Could do with being more specific to the actual case.

Comment: @NeilLunn I would be totally ok to store the priority for each user in another way if it permits to solve the business requirement. Would it allow to solve the problem? Can I say in my paginated query that I want to weigh more some documents by Id for example?

Comment: I think maybe if you could provide some samples and explain what the action is that has to happen. i.e This data, what user does, expected end result. Much like a protracted discussion I just went through, it would be good if questions did not try to draw their own conclusions, and simply state those "I have this", "this interaction happens", "this should be the observed result" basic points. For me, if you simply demonstrate those things, it becomes clear as to what solution to apply.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've edited my question